# Two way Platform Unity 2D Game Development

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

I am trying to make a platform that you can jump through and then when you press "Down" you can jump off the platform.

The problem is that when you press "Down" all the GameObjects on the platform fall down along with the player.

I managed to make a script using some tutorials that uses the "Platform Effector 2D" using this script.

```
private PlatformEffector2D effector;
    public float waitTime;
    void Start()
    {
        effector = GetComponent<PlatformEffector2D>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))
        {
            waitTime = 0.5f;
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            if(waitTime <= 0)
            {
                effector.rotationalOffset = 180f;
                waitTime = 0.5f;
            }
            else
            {
                waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            effector.rotationalOffset = 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What is the question?

Comment: I want to be able to allow the player to jump up and down the platform. I can do that by using the Effector but if the player jumps off the platform, every single enemy or object on the platform falls with him.